# Can you tell what is the problem in the Code?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures

**Question is given that we have to find the duplicate number in an array. Can someone please tell  me why this code is not working?**

```cpp
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12,13,14,15,15,10};

    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int n;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                 n =  arr[i];
                 break;
            }
            
        }
   
    }

    cout<<n;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me the problem.

Comment: In your loops, ```i``` can be equal to ```j```, so the program will erroneously return 1 as a duplicate element since ```arr[1] == arr[1]```

Answer (score 1):

You need to let *j* start from *i+1*, or it may match itself as the duplicate number.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 10};

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                n = arr[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, n is unintialized and if no duplicate is found, it will output garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `for loop` doesn't break when duplicate is found. You can use another variable and set it to `true` if duplicate element is found.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 10};

    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int n = 0;
    bool duplicate_found = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                n = arr[i];
                duplicate_found = true;
            }
            
        }
        if (duplicate_found) break;
    }

    cout << n;
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Don't use `goto` statement here. It's a bad practice to use `goto`. And as @schtonn suggested start your inner loop from `i+1`.

Answer (score -2):

`break` takes you out of the inner loop only. If you want to break out of both loops, you need `goto` statement.